# How to pass command output as several arguments to another command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a command that produces output like this:

```
$ ./command1
word1 word2 word3
```

I want to pass these three words as arguments to another command like this:

```
$ command2 word1 word2 word3
```

How to pass command1 output as three different arguments $1 $2 $3 to command2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems the best way to separate the output from command1 and send it to command2 as three different arguments is to use xargs with -t option which is passing all as argument like this:

```
$ ./command1 | xargs -t command2
```

Source

https://serverfault.com/users/249134/chaosc

Answer (score 1):

Just use an unquoted command substitution:

```
$ ./command2 $(./command1)
```

However, this also subjects the output of `command1` to pathname generation, so if the output could include something like `*.txt`, you risk that being expanded to multiple words before being passed to `command2`. In that case, you'll need to use

```
$ read arg1 arg2 arg3 <<< "$(./command1)"
$ ./command2 "$arg1" "$arg2" "$arg3"
```

or

```
$ read -a args <<< "$(./command1)"
$ ./command2 "${args[@]}"
```

to split the output into 3 words without subjecting them to pathname generation.

---

This won't work if the output of `command1` looks like

```
"word1a word1b" word2
```

and you expect to be able to pass two arguments, `word1a word1b` and `word2` to `command2`, but getting that right is sufficiently tricky to require more details about what `command1` could output to provide the correct solution.

Comment: command1 produces output as plain text: hostname:port username password. command2 suppose to read three arguments again like hostname:port username password

Comment: In that case, I would recommend the version using `read`. I assume that neither the host, port, nor user-name can contain any whitespace, but I would hesitate to make any assumptions about the password. (It would fail if the password begins or ends with whitespace, but I seen no way to detect that from the described output of `command1` anyway).